# How do I check if there are items in the database Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Disclaimer: I've just started with `Django` a couple of days ago so I'm still quite new to it, patience, please.
Alright, so I have two different models in my `models` file. One of them is the Order with certain order attributes and the other one is Counter, an assistant model so to say. The idea is that I need to check the database if an order exists, if it doesn't, I need to give Counter the value of 1 as this will be the first order, then the value needs to be assigned to the code of the Order model. On the other hand, if an order does exist, then increment a counter by 1. Here's my approach and it's getting me this error as the value of code: `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x04996280>`

Here is the simplified version of the models. Also, quick question, am I right to do this part on the `models` file? Should I do it on the serializer or views or it doesn't really change anything. Thanks in advance.

```
class Order(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=True)
    code_year = models.IntegerField
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.code = Counter.name
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You could use signals to trigger the `Counter`. A `pre_save` signal to the `Order` model could work. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can get the count of existing orders, increment it and append in `code` field with formatted string.

```
class Order(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=True)
    code_year = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_length])
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            counter = Order.objects.latest('id').id + 1
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            counter = 1
        self.code = f"P + {counter} + {self.code_year}"
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Many many thanks for the answer, I'll stick with this, works flawlessly and it's super clear. Thanks mate^^

Answer (score 0):

Django does all of that for you,
I recommend taking some time to check the forms and model documentation, as well as the tutorial it is really worth the time.

most relevant to your question:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related
```

generally worth a read:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/
```

after the comments i think you want to do this:

```
class Order:
    ....
    ....
    def get_code()
        return f"{self.id}-{self.customer_id.year_joined}"
```

note that i expect customer_id to be the foreign key to associate the order with a customer, django will automatically resolve that for you, so customer_id is not an id but rather the customer object.
edit: i could have sworn that select_related() was part of the second tutorial, however that is the function you may need later on to get the amount of orders related to an order type.

Comment: Many thanks for the links, however I did check out the one that you said was relevant to my question and I'm failing to find an answer. I'm not sure if I'm looking on the right direction or not. When I look at the code that I wrote, logically to me atleast, it should work and that's why I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Django creates all the id's for you, you only need to worry about the data you want to store, so you just need to create an order with all the related informations. If you want something like order types, then you need a model order types, where every order references a certain order type. You can then simply query the amount of orders associated with that order type.

Comment: I'm aware that Django does create the ids for you, I noticed that in the database. And there are also other fields in the Order model with other attributes. Now what I want to do, is find a way to check if an object exists in the database, so an order was made, and increment the counter function that I have setup (which I'm not sure if I've done so correctly). Perhaps you might be explaining what I need to do but I'm just not getting it sorry.

Comment: for me an order can only be singular, so 
customer does order -> order is done and completed |
customer does another order -> order has new id, and is done and completed.
So any order id can only have one associated order and there may never be 2 of the same order.
if you want to have something like order classes, e.g. local, pickup,... and you want to know how many were done for each class you can associate every order to a class, and then if you wish to know the number you can use orderclass.select_related('order') .count() to get the number of orders with that class.

Comment: Perhaps we're not on the same page. So the field code is not gonna be just the number, for that I would've just used the ID which as u said Django does it for me. The idea behind code is its needs to be of this format: "P+(value that starts from 0 and increments if an order is created) + year that the user registers". And that has to be set as the value of Code.

Comment: you can add a custom function to the model, that generates the code for you, i would not save it in the database, as that would add redundant information into your database. i will add an example to my answer.

Comment: I get how that would be better, maybe using UUID but this is something that I have to see through unfortunatley.

Comment: i think that example above works well with your id assuming that you have a customer table associated with your orders, maybe you need to set order id to be an integer instead of an uuid, in case you want more human readable order codes.

Comment: So you think the code is right as well, same here. So i do have customer tables that are associated but when trying to create a new object, the value of code goes automatically to the one that I stated before, that DeferredAttribute thing. Not quite sure what's going on with that.

Comment: No i think, that the entire Count model is unnecessary and a waste of space and that you can solve your problem with adding a single line function to your Order class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `Order` class itself.

Generate the `code` that you require in the `save()` method.

```
class Order(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=True)
    code_year = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_length])
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        code_gen = f'P-{self.id}-{self.code_year}'
        Order.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(code=code_gen)
```

Comment: Okay so definetly progress, I don't see that weird django error thing anymore. Now it displays "P-None-2021". Any idea on why the counter might not be working?

Comment: Oops! Now I remember, django generates ```id``` after the object is saved and not before. So you need to first save, then generate the code and then save.

Comment: Right but it shouldn't be the ID, it has the be the counter.value on the other model. So is my way of checking if there are objects and then incrementing correct?

Comment: I tried what you edited, it was raising some new errors. I'm sticking with another anwer that someone else posted but thanks so much for the effort mate^^